# Passing FacebookContext Facebook App

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, facebook-c#-sdk

I am trying to do Jquery call on click of an element, on controller side i have this below, this is from Facebook C# mvc template.

```
 [FacebookAuthorize("email", "friends_birthday")]
    public async Task<ActionResult> GetFriends(FacebookContext context)
    {
        try
        {


        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var user = await context.Client.GetCurrentUserAsync<MyAppUser>();
            var friendsWithUpcomingBirthdays = user.Friends.Data.Take(100);
            user.Friends.Data = friendsWithUpcomingBirthdays.ToList();
            return PartialView("MyFriends", user);
        }

        return View("Error");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

        return View("Error");
    }

}
```

since i am trying to call using jquery inside a javascript file i tired using

```
@Html.Hidden("MyFriends", GlobalFacebookConfiguration.Configuration.AppUrl@Url.Action("GetFriends", "Home"))
```

and on my Jquery i do

```
var myUrl = $("#MyFriends").val();
    $.get(myUrl, function (data) {
        $('#detailsDiv').replaceWith(data);
    });
```

**But i get error on my     @Html.Hidden("MyFriends", GlobalFacebookConfiguration.Configuration.AppUrl@Url.Action("GetFriends", "Home"))
saying ") expected ; expected"**
[image]

Any Ideas?

Comment: What is the following code attempting to do?  Do you need to concatenate these values?  You can only type @Url without a space, when you are mashing up against HTML markup.  You can't mash up C# like that.  GlobalFacebookConfiguration.Configuration.AppUrl@Url.Action

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like :

```
@Html.Hidden("MyFriends", GlobalFacebookConfiguration.Configuration.AppUrl + "/" + @Url.Action("GetFriends", "Home"))
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use Razor @Html helpers in a js file.  Instead, add it to a cshtml file.

Comment: this is not a js file this is cshtlm file. @html helper is in cshtml, jqeruy is in javascript file

Comment: Oh, I was confused by the statement : "since i am trying to call using jquery inside a javascript file i tired using" then the @Html helper